# Visual Basics: Rainfall Stats

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to figure out what I am missing.  I have already submitted this homework assignment as you see it.  When returning the rainfall min and max stats, you should also be bringing over what month goes with the min and max.  I have try many different ways but nothing seems to work.  What am I missing?  No rush, as I it was due April 19th, but I have already submitted it.  Just trying to see where I have gone wrong.

```
Const intMONTHS As Integer = 11
Dim sngRain(intMONTHS) As Single
Dim strMonths() As String = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
       "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
       "December"}
Private Sub btnInput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInput.Click
    lstOutput.Items.Add("Monthly Rainfall Input")
    lstOutput.Items.Add("___________________________")
    GetRainAmount(sngRain)

End Sub

Sub GetRainAmount(ByRef sngRain() As Single)
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Do While intCount < sngRain.Length
        Try
            sngRain(intCount) =
                CDec(InputBox("Please enter the amount of Rain(in inches) for " & strMonths(intCount)))
            lstOutput.Items.Add(("Rainfall for " & strMonths(intCount) & " = " & sngRain(intCount)))
            intCount += 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid numeric value.")
        End Try
    Loop
End Sub

Function Total(ByVal sngRain() As Single) As Single
    Dim sngTotal As Single = 0
    Dim intCount As Integer

    For intCount = 0 To (sngRain.Length - 1)
        sngTotal += sngRain(intCount)

    Next
    Return sngTotal
End Function

Function Average(ByVal sngRain() As Single) As Single
    Return Total(sngRain) / strMonths.Length
End Function

Function Minimum(ByVal sngRain() As Single) As Single
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim sngMinimum As Single
    Dim intminIndex As Integer

    sngMinimum = sngRain(0)

    For intCount = 0 To (sngRain.Length - 1)
        If sngRain(intCount) < sngMinimum Then
            sngMinimum = sngRain(intCount)
            intminIndex = intCount
        End If
    Next
    Return sngMinimum

End Function
Function Maximum(ByVal sngRain() As Single) As Single
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim sngMaximum As Single
    Dim intmaxIndex As Integer

    sngMaximum = sngRain(0)

    For intCount = 0 To (sngRain.Length - 1)
        If sngRain(intCount) > sngMaximum Then
            sngMaximum = sngRain(intCount)
            intmaxIndex = CInt(strMonths(intCount))
        End If
    Next
    Return sngMaximum

End Function

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    Dim intminIndex As Integer
    Dim intmaxIndex As Integer
    Dim sngTotal As Single
    Dim sngAverage As Single
    Dim sngMinimum As Single
    Dim sngMaximum As Single

    sngTotal = Total(sngRain)
    sngAverage = Average(sngRain)
    sngMinimum = Minimum(sngRain)
    sngMaximum = Maximum(sngRain)

    lblTotalRain.Text = ("The total annual rainfall was " & sngTotal)
    lblAverage.Text = ("The average monthly rainfall was " & sngAverage)
    lblMinimum.Text = ("The minimum monthly rainfall was " & sngMinimum & "(" & strMonths(intminIndex) & ")")
    lblMaximum.Text = ("The maximum monthly rainfall was " & sngMaximum & "(" & strMonths(intmaxIndex) & ")")
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    lstOutput.Items.Clear()
    lblTotalRain.Text = String.Empty
    lblAverage.Text = String.Empty
    lblMinimum.Text = String.Empty
    lblMaximum.Text = String.Empty

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: A Class is ideal for linking different bits of information especially when they are not the same type {month (string), min (int?) max (int) avg (single)}

Comment: Where do you call `GetRainAmount`?

Comment: I just made that name up.  I could have named it anything, went with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be properly setting intmaxIndex in the Maximum function and intminIndex in the Minimum function, but those values are local to each function.  Those variables in btnDisplay_Click are then not being set.

You can get the min and max month index by passing the intminIndex and intmaxIndex variables ByRef into the Minimum and Maximum functions respectively.

```
Function Minimum(ByVal sngRain() As Single, ByRef intminIndex as Integer) As Single
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim sngMinimum As Single

    sngMinimum = sngRain(0)

    For intCount = 0 To (sngRain.Length - 1)
        If sngRain(intCount) < sngMinimum Then
            sngMinimum = sngRain(intCount)
            intminIndex = intCount
        End If
    Next
    Return sngMinimum

End Function
Function Maximum(ByVal sngRain() As Single, ByRef intmaxIndex as Integer) As Single
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim sngMaximum As Single

    sngMaximum = sngRain(0)

    For intCount = 0 To (sngRain.Length - 1)
        If sngRain(intCount) > sngMaximum Then
            sngMaximum = sngRain(intCount)
            intmaxIndex = intCount
        End If
    Next
    Return sngMaximum

End Function

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    Dim intminIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim intmaxIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim sngTotal As Single
    Dim sngAverage As Single
    Dim sngMinimum As Single
    Dim sngMaximum As Single

    sngTotal = Total(sngRain)
    sngAverage = Average(sngRain)
    sngMinimum = Minimum(sngRain, intminIndex)
    sngMaximum = Maximum(sngRain, intmaxIndex)

    lblTotalRain.Text = ("The total annual rainfall was " & sngTotal)
    lblAverage.Text = ("The average monthly rainfall was " & sngAverage)
    lblMinimum.Text = ("The minimum monthly rainfall was " & sngMinimum & "(" & strMonths(intminIndex) & ")")
    lblMaximum.Text = ("The maximum monthly rainfall was " & sngMaximum & "(" & strMonths(intmaxIndex) & ")")
End Sub
```

Comment: heapunderflow: thanks much.  It works perfectly now.  Wish I would have caught that prior to sending in the work.  Thank you for pointing that out.